# JHipster authentication using Postman and JWT

Tags: jwt, jhipster, postman

I'd been using the Postman in-tab extension to tests calls to call JHipster resource API's and found that it worked great (JHipster setup to use OAuth2).  I authenticated using the JHipster login page, then opened up a new tab with the Postman extension.

I just switched my JHipster application to use JWT and this method of using Postman no longer works, I get permission denied when calling the API. Moreover, the in-tab extension for Postman is being deprecated in favor of the stand-alone app.

Question: Is there any documentation on setting up Postman for authenticating against JHipster/JWT?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Make a POST request to `/api/authenticate` with the following body:
   `{"password":"admin","username":"admin"}`. You will receive the following response: `{"id_token":"aabbccddeeff"}`
2. Make your subsequent requests using the value of the token received in the previous call and put in into an `Authorization: Bearer aabbccddeeff`
3. You can check the status of the authentication, making a GET request to `/api/authenticate` endpoint

Comment: unfortunately, I get an error 403 when I try to use the default admin credentials

Comment: For me it says,

{
    "type": "http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/api/authenticate",
    "message": "error.http.401"
}

Comment: For me returns success (200) but without token.

Comment: I put example curl calls for this check http://blog.mascix.com/2021/10/jhipster-login-and-how-to-call-rest-api.html

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to use Postman with a JWT JHipster app.

1. First, authenticate with the JHipster app
2. Inspect any API request for the `Authorization` header.  The JWT token is the value to the right of "Bearer ".  You can also find this token in the browser's localStorage under the key `jhi-authenticationToken`.
3. Edit the headers in Postman and add the `Authorization` header.  The value should look like the following:

   ```
   Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJydRkZWxsIiwiYXV0aCI6IlJPTEVfQURNSU4sUk9MRV9U0VSIiwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTg1MDkzfQ.1A13sBvr3KDWxJQpKDKOS33KAVjWIb3mS_qfxLBOCq_LbMwNHnysAai0SNXXgudMOulAnXYN9_Mzlcv1_zctA
   ```

Comment: This works but it's a pain in the you-know-what. Having to copy paste in the authorization for each request after a new login slows one down and one loses the ability to iterate quickly.

Comment: @geoidesic use a environment variable. Then you can have all of your apis like Bearer {{token}}.

Answer (score 12):

If you have deployed a single microservice and you want to test it in isolation you can configure Postman to build a JWT token using a pre-request script.

1. Go to the `application-dev.yml` file generated by JHipster and grab the `base64-secret` value:

```yaml
security:
    authentication:
        jwt:
            # This token must be encoded using Base64 and be at least 256 bits long (you can type `openssl rand -base64 64` on your command line to generate a 512 bits one)
            base64-secret: N2Y2MmFkNzg2ZTI4NTZiZGEwMTZhYTAzOTBhMjgwMzlkMzU2MzRlZjJjZDA2MzQ0NGMxOGFlZThjOWY0MjkzNGVlOGE3ZjkxZGI5ZTQxOGY3MjEwNWUwYTUxMTUxODYxY2U4ZWMzZjVhMjg0NTZkNzlhNWUyMmEyNjQ5NzkxZmI=
```

2. Put the value in a variable named `jhipster_jwt_secret` inside the Postman Environment.
3. Configure your pre-request script ([this is largely copied from a Gist](https://gist.github.com/corbanb/db03150abbe899285d6a86cc480f674d)):

```js
function base64url(source) {
    // Encode in classical base64
    encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);

    // Remove padding equal characters
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');

    // Replace characters according to base64url specifications
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');

    return encodedSource;
}

var header = {
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "HS256"
};

var payload = {
  "sub": "user",
  "auth": "role"
};

var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("jhipster_jwt_secret"));

// encode header
var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
var encodedHeader = base64url(stringifiedHeader);

// encode data
var stringifiedPayload = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
var encodedPayload = base64url(stringifiedPayload);

// build token
var token = encodedHeader + "." + encodedPayload;

// sign token
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, secret);
signature = base64url(signature);
var signedToken = token + "." + signature;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("jwt_token", signedToken);
```

4. Inside the Authorization tab select "Bearer token" and write `{{jwt_token}}` in the Token input field.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, since I have a microservice with JWT authentication. and it works perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: This is a good advice. Thank you.
But here I have to take the secret from jhipster-registry configuration. How are you developing a microservice without a jhipster-registry instance?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for me is

1. log into your Jhipster Web app with the admin credential
2. Select Administration > API

[image]

3. Then choose any of existing API and click 'Try it out' button
   [image]

It will list a `curl` action with the token, now you can grab the token and use it in Postman