# How to get and use authentication token for JHipster Microservice JWT

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jhipster

I created a JHipster microservice App with JWT authentication (I only have the "backend", no Angular GUI).

In my application-dev.yml, I have the following lines:

```
jhipster:
    security:
      authentication:
        jwt:
            secret: password
            # Token is valid 24 hours
            token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
            token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
```

How can I access the API with a client like "Restlet" (Google Chrome extension).

I read something about getting the token when accessing /api/authenticate but it didn't work ([JHipster authentication using Postman and JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107442/jhipster-authentication-using-postman-and-jwt))

Where can I retrieve the JWT Token and how to use it in subsequent requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a token from the JHipster registry.
Use a Post to:
http://[JhipsterRegistryIP]:[JHPORT]/api/authenticate

with in header:

Content-Type: application/json

and in body:

{"password": "YOURADMINPASSWORD","rememberMe": true,"username": "admin"}

You get a response with token like this:

{
"id_token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTY1MTMxMjE3M30.ywNnrHv-QTjeCDEAjxYhfpOabzmYpSsJufQYlL-dV7NB683rFiCtFvwTYTZuqlu6XBMEKI13_SLFZM3eF8kxgQ"
}

Now you can make a request to your microservice with in header:

Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTY1MTMxMjE3M30.ywNnrHv-QTjeCDEAjxYhfpOabzmYpSsJufQYlL-dV7NB683rFiCtFvwTYTZuqlu6XBMEKI13_SLFZM3eF8kxgQ"

Answer (score 8):

You've chosen a microservices architecture: so now you need a registry and a gateway( read [the doc](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/)).

You get a token by authenticating against the gateway then you use this token by passing it on each request with Authorization http header.

Comment: If we want to have the sessionless tocken, we just wanted to save the tocken along with the user table, pass the same tocken on every request till i update the new  tocken. Is this possible to achieve with current Jhipster version

Comment: Everything is possible, it's just a code generator. You can  do what you want with generated code, it's yours.

Comment: I was expecting some help from your people. I know that was my code. Answer was just to comment but not related to any help.